# C statement's side effect and sequence point

Tags: c, expression

Greetings to all the expert again , and again I stumble across a few questions.

**The Story :**

I read a book mentions that a sequence point which is `;` is a point where all the side effect before it should be evaluated before it advanced to the next statement.In order to make the context of my question clean , I will write a simple code.

**The Code :**

```
while (guess++ < 10)
{
   printf("%d \n" , guests);
```

**My Thinking and the Question:**

1.)From the above code, the `while` statement test condition `guess++ < 10` is a full expression.So in my mindset it is not a statement because it doesn't end with a `;`.

2.)Since a postfix increment operator is used , therefore the `guess` value evaluated before it is incremented.

3.)The book mention that the increment operation is carry out right after the `guess` variable is used for the relational operation , then only the `printf()` function would carry out its duty.

4.)My question is that , since the test condition doesn't end with a `;` , therefore it's not a statement . But why the increment operation implemented before  `printf()` function is called , but not after the `print()` function only it is being incremented??

5.)Maybe this is a side question , the book mention that `while` is a structured statement , but why didn't I see a trailing `;` is append on it `while(testcondition);`.

6.)It might sounds like a silly question , but sometime when I read some source code written by others , I will saw some of them place the open braces `{` of while loop on the same line with the `while()` , which causes it to be like that `while(testcondition){` . Is this a convention or is there any special reason for doing this??

*Thanks for spending time reading my problems , your help is much appreciated.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering question 1: The code between the brackets of a while loop is actually a full expression. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

> This category includes expression statements (such as the assignment a=b;), return statements, the controlling expressions of if, switch, while, or do-while statements, and all three expressions in a for statement.

A good description of a full expression can be found in the C faq:

> full expression
>   The complete expression that forms an expression statement, or one of the controlling expressions of an if, switch, while, for, or do/while statement, or the expression in an initializer or a return statement. A full expression is not part of a larger expression. (See ANSI Sec. 3.6 or ISO Sec. 6.6.)

It's important to note that a full expression has nothing to do with a statement or the semi-colon token.

So lets dig into this a little bit.  Fixing up your code snippit I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned guess = 0;
    while (guess++ < 10)
    {
       printf("%d " , guess);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces this output:

> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

So that means that the evaluation would be equivalent to this code:

```
while (guess < 10)
{
    guess++;
    printf("%d " , guess);
}
```

The answer to question 5 can be found in this stackoverflow question:
[In C/C++ why does the do while(expression); need a semi colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942251/in-c-c-why-does-the-do-whileexpression-need-a-semi-colon)