# When is a semicolon after } mandated in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

```
if(...) {
  ...
}
```

It seems in the above case a `;` is optional,when is a semicolon after `}` necessary in c/c++?

Comment: Semicolon there is NOT optional.  This `if(a) if(b) { ... } else { ... }` means one thing, while `if(a) if(b) { ... }; else { ... }` is a syntax error (`else` without matching `if`).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Are your aware of any other constructs like `if-else`, `do-while` and `try-catch` where semicolon after brace can be illegal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
int a[2] = {1,2}, j = 5;
```

When initialization of array or structure are done with `{}` all the subsequent variables are declared after `,`.

**Edit**: As you changed your question; `;` is mandatory after the `class`, `enum`, *initialization* syntax declarations.

```
class A {};  // same for `struct
enum E {};   // enum class (c++0x)
int a[] = {1,2};  // array or object initialization
```

And as per comment by @rubenvb:

```
do {} while(condition);
```

Comment: any rational behind all these?

Comment: @cpuer It's not a rationale but `struct { int i; } s;` is meaningful in C and C++. When you don't need the object(s) (here, `s`), then the `;` remains.

Comment: @cpuer: For the `class` and `enum` examples, I explained in comments on Ernest's answer. For the array or object initializations, you need a semicolon simply because they are statements and all statements are terminated by `;`s :)

Comment: @cpuer, as @Luc said, since in `C++` you can declare objects/pointers after the `class/struct/enum` declaration. Putting a `;` helps the parser that one has to type the `class` name to declare any object. Since function / `namespace' are not type; the `;` after them is not mandatory.

Comment: Don't forget a [`do{ ... } while(...);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942251/in-c-c-why-does-the-do-whileexpression-need-a-semi-colon)

Answer (score 6):

A semicolon by itself is an *empty statement*, and you can add extra ones anywhere a statement is legal. Therfore it would be legal to put a semicolon right after the braces following your `if`, although it wouldn't be related to the `if` at all. The only place I can think of where a semicolon is *required* right after a bracket is after a class declaration in C++.

Comment: Why `;` is required after class declaration but not after function declaration? C++ parser can't parse it without the `;` in that case?

Comment: @cpuer: Because you can declare instances at the definition site. For example: `struct ABC { int foo; int bar; } example;` creates a variable named `example` of type `ABC`.

Answer (score 4):

A semicolon after a close brace is manadatory if this is the end of a *declaration*.  If it is the end of a *block statement* then no semicolon is needed, and if one is used, it makes an additional empty *statement*, which may be illegal if this is the middle of a `if`-`else` or a `do`-`while` (or a `try`-`catch` in C++)

---

Semicolons are required many places *not* after a close brace (at the end of any statement except a block-statement, at the end of any declaration, even if there is no `}`, in a `for` clause, etc, but generally braces are not involved in any of those.

Comment: a `do-while` needs a semi-colon at the end!

Comment: @rubenvb: if you try to put a `;` after the `}` in a `do`-`while` loop, you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: but it is needed after the final `)`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Are your aware of any other constructs like `if-else`, `do-while` and `try-catch` where semicolon after brace can be illegal?